# MATLAB GUI callback not setting values for another callback?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, handles

I want one button press to set the value and another button press to output the value of a variable. It seems the value is not set by the first button press using the following code. Why is that?

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.dog=1001

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles
disp(num2str(handles.dog))   % <-- value not present
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `guidata(hObject, handles);` at the end of your `pushbutton2_Callback to update the handles structure, so you can access it from the other function.

So, your resulting code would be:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.dog=1001
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles
disp(num2str(handles.dog))   % <-- value not present
```

Answer (score 0):

use `guidata(hObject, handles);` after setting value to preserve it

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.dog=1001

guidata(hObject, handles);
```